# Is there a way to get a reference to all the child windows or controls on an MFC dialog, given that I have a CWnd object referencing that control?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, controls

Lets say I have an MFC Dialog with several buttons on it. (E.g. "Red", "Blue", "Green", and "Yellow" buttons) These buttons all have IDs such as `("IDC_BUTT_RED","IDC_BUTT_BLUE","IDC_BUTT_GREEN","IDC_BUTT_YELLOW")`

Given that I have a CWnd object that references the dialog window that these buttons are placed on. Is there a way to get a list of these IDs?

I know there is a `CWnd::GetNextDlgGroupItem` method, that based on the description should iterate through a group of controls. I tried using it, passing in a CWnd object referring to one of the buttons, then calling the `GetWindowText` method to check, but it always returns a reference to itself.

Comment: [GetNextDlgGroupItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645492.aspx) returns a handle to the control starting the next group, i.e. the next control with a `WS_GROUP` window style. If your dialog has a single group of buttons, the described behavior is expected. You also seem to confuse the compile time named constants with IDs: IDs are `1`, `2`, and so on. There is no symbolic information left in the compiled code. There is no way to retrieve the string `"IDC_BUTT_RED"` from a control at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enumerate all of the dialog's child windows using EnumChildWindows. This is a C API function so you use and get HWNDs instead of CWnds. When each child window's HWND is passed to your callback function you can call GetClassName to find its window class name (like "BUTTON") and GetWindowLong to find its ID.

Comment: Or you can: `CWnd* pChild = pDlg->GetWindow(GW_CHILD); while (pChild) { ....; pChild = pChild->GetNextWindow(); }`