# Get all control IDs of MFC dialog box

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Is there some way to get all control IDs of current MFC dialog box? (to change WindowText of all controls)

Comment: See [Is there a way to get a reference to all the child windows or controls on an MFC dialog, given that I have a CWnd object referencing that control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788886/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-reference-to-all-the-child-windows-or-controls-on-an-mfc).

Comment: Why would you need control IDs for that? What would you do when an ID is shared by more than one control (which is frequently the case with STATIC controls)?

Comment: @IInspectable Maybe it is his own style of multi-language support that does not use resource only satellite DLL files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
for(CWnd* pWnd = GetWindow(GW_CHILD); pWnd != NULL; pWnd = pWnd->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT))
{
    pWnd->SetWindowText(_T("MyText"));
}
```

Of course, you can check ID or type of control id if you need.